# Delete this instance of a loop in VueJs

Tags: vue.js

Is there any way in which I can delete the instance of the loop from the "loop component", sorry, it's hard to explain without the proper knowledge.

I need to make the "templateContract" disappear but I would like to avoid sending variables from child to parent to delete the item from the array with the index. Maybe removing the element from the dom?

I have a for looping my array like this.

```html
<template>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 mb-3" :class="{'disabled': disable}" v-for="templateContract, index in templateContracts" :key="templateContract.id" :id="templateContract.id">
        <template-contract-listing-item-component :templateContract="templateContract"></template-contract-listing-item-component>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And this "template-contract-listing-item-component looks like this.

```html
<template>
  <div class="row custom-contract-row">
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 custom-contract-content">
      <div class="title-underline">
        <div>
          <h4 class="mt-2 template-title" v-if="!edit">{{templateContract.title}}<font-awesome-icon icon="pen" class="ml-3 h6 edit-title-icon" /></h4>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" v-if="edit" v-model="templateContract.title" />
          <h5 class="template-usecasetitle" v-if="!edit">({{templateContract.usecasetitle}})</h5>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" v-if="edit" v-model="templateContract.usecasetitle" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row pt-2">
        <div class="col-12 mb-5 pb-5 p-1 pr-3 pl-lg-3 template-contract-description">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" v-if="edit" v-model="templateContract.description" />
          <h5 class="font-weight-normal" v-if="!edit">
            {{ templateContract.description }}
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex action-buttons">
        <div class=""><router-link to="/edit-template-contract" tag="a" class="btn btn-primary">Klauseln bearbeiten</router-link></div>
        <div class=""><button class="btn btn-primary" @click="remove(templateContract)">Muster löschen</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="edit-template-data-icon"  @click="edit = !edit"><font-awesome-icon icon="pen" /></span>
    <span class="edit-template-data-icon" v-if="edit" @click="updateTemplate(templateContract)"><font-awesome-icon icon="check" /></span>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<script>
import TemplateContractListingItemComponent from "./TemplateContractListingItemComponent";
import ContractTypeService from "@/services/ContractTypeService";

export default {
  name: "template-contract-listing-component",
  components: {
    "template-contract-listing-item-component": TemplateContractListingItemComponent
  },
  props: {
    templateContract: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      edit: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getDateYear: function(dateString)
    {
      return dateString.substring(0, 4);
    },
    getDateDayMonth: function(dateString)
    {
      return dateString.substring(0, 10).split("-").reverse().join("-").substring(0, 5).replace('-', '.');
    },
    async updateTemplate(templateContract)
    {
      this.edit = false;
      const {
          body: { data },
        } = await ContractTypeService.update(templateContract.id, templateContract, "templatecontract");
        return data;
    },
    async remove(templateContract)
    {
      if(confirm("Wollen Sie den Vertrag wirklich löschen?"))
      {
        const {
          body: { data },
        } = await ContractTypeService.delete("templatecontract", templateContract.id);
        return data;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: You have an error in your `v-for` expression. It should be `v-for="(templateContract, index) in templateContracts" `

Comment: _"I need to make the "templateContract" disappear"_. Disappear how? What triggers this disappearance?

Comment: Hello thanks! I will fix it. It works anyways.
I have this function "remove()" triggered here:
@click="remove(templateContract)"
That triggers the php. But I also need to remove the element from the DOM. I would like to do it on the same remove() function.

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues with your current implementation...

1. Prop attributes should be [kebab-cased](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case)

   ```
   :template-contract="templateContract"
   ```
2. You are directly modifying prop data in your child component. This violates Vue's [One-Way Data Flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) principal.

   Instead, create a local copy of the prop and use that in your template's `v-model` bindings

   ```js
   props: { templateContract: Object },
   data: vm => ({
     tc: { ...vm.templateContract } // local copy for editing
   })
   ```

   ```html
   <!-- use the "tc" local copy -->
   <h4 class="mt-2 template-title" v-if="!edit">
     {{tc.title}}
     <font-awesome-icon icon="pen" class="ml-3 h6 edit-title-icon" />
   </h4>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" v-if="edit" v-model="tc.title" />
   <!-- etc -->
   ```
3. Your `v-for` expression is incorrect

   Use this instead since you're not using `index` anyway

   ```
   v-for="templateContract in templateContracts"
   ```
4. To modify data in the parent component, the child should *emit* events

   You should emit an event from the child component and add an event handler in the parent to remove it from the array. I would also do something similar for the *update* event

   Something like this (in `template-contract-listing-component`)

   ```js
   async updateTemplate()
   {
     this.edit = false;
     const {
         body: { data },
       } = await ContractTypeService.update(this.tc.id, this.tc, "templatecontract");
     this.$emit('update-template', this.tc) // updated templateContract in payload
     return data;
   },
   async remove()
   {
     if(confirm("Wollen Sie den Vertrag wirklich löschen?"))
     {
       const {
         body: { data },
       } = await ContractTypeService.delete("templatecontract", this.tc.id);
       this.$emit('remove-template') // no need for a payload, let the parent handle it
       return data;
     }
   }
   ```

   and in the parent

   ```html
   <template-contract-listing-item-component
     :template-contract="templateContract"
     @remove-template="removeTemplate(templateContract)"
     @update-template="updateTemplate"
   ></template-contract-listing-item-component>
   ```

   ```js
   methods: {
     removeTemplate (templateContract) {
       this.templateContracts.splice(
         this.templateContracts.indexOf(templateContract), 1)
     },
     updateTemplate (updatedTc) {
       const index = this.templateContracts.findIndex(({ id }) => id === updatedTc.id)
       if (index >= 0) {
         // replace the old templateContract with the new one
         // use splice() so it's reactive
         this.templateContracts.splice(index, 1, updatedTc)
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have no idea what I'm doing actually. And yes, that's exactly what I wanted to avoid, emitting events. It seems to me very complicated solution to a very small task. But it seems that is the only and standard solution.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid emitting events? That's exactly how Vue (and React too) are engineered to work. I suggest you read the documentation I linked about _one-way data flow_